# How can I detect the element inside another element while the event is set to the outer one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code:

```js
$("div").on('click', function(e){
  
    e.preventDefault(e);

  /*
  if ( clicked element is <a> element ){
  
    redirect to the href
    and return false
    
  }
  */
  
  alert("div clicked");
  
})
```

```css
div{
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>this is a paragraph</p>
  <a href="/url">this is a link</a>
  <p>this is another paragraph</p>
</div>
```

How can I make that condition *(which is commented in code above)* working? I need to detect if the clicked element inside `<div>` is a `<a>`, then redirect to it and die. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `e.target` to get the clicked element. To check what tag is clicked, you can use `e.target.tagName`

```js
$("div").on('click', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault(e);

  if ( e.target.tagName === 'A' ) {
      var href = $(e.target).attr('href');
      console.log(href);
  }

  //e.target.tagName - Will return 'A' if <a> is clicked.

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>this is a paragraph</p>
  <a href="/url">this is a link</a>
  <p>this is another paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Very good .. thank you, uvpote. Just can I get other attributes of the clicked element? *(not just the name)*

Comment: yes, you can. you can use use `$(e.target).attr('href');` to get the href for example

Comment: As a note `e.target.href` would work well *(if you want to use vanilla JS)*.